# Redirect a directory to root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a directory named "user" in my root directory. Now I'd like to rewrite "user" to root, so that for example */user/account.php* can be accessed like this *www.mydomain.com/account.php*.

I found an example for a similar problem an modified it to my needs, however, it does not work as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /user/(.*) /$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Both

*www.mydomain.com/account.php*

and

*www.mydomain.com/user/account.php*

redirect me to root, instead of taking me to the account.php page...

Comment: May be you have redirect code in account.php script?

Comment: I don't. I also tried other files in "users" with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
RewriteRule /user/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

Try to replace `/user/(.*)$  with ^user/(.*)$`
Also the $1 will redirect yourdomain.com/user/whatever to yourdomain.com/whatever

so just write

```
RewriteRule ^user/account.php / [L]
```

or if you only have account.php and user account.php
you could use this line instead

```
RewriteRule ^account.php / [L]
```

This will make every URL that ends with account.php redirected to /

Hope this one helps.

Comment: Okay, ^user/(.*)$ lead to "File not found"-errors, so I used ^/user/(.*)$ The rule now is "RewriteRule ^/uc/(.*)$ / [L]". I can access www.mydomain.com/user/account.php, but it does not rewrite anything. www.mydomain.com/account.php is a "File not found"...

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite?
Also do you have `AllowOverride All` in your config, so you can use .htaccess?

Comment: I have mod_rewrite enabled. Actually, I am on XAMPP and I am starting to think that this might be sort of a caching issure. I have just reset my .htaccess file, but it still keeps redirecting me...